# Want to run mutiple choices in a order picked by the user

Tags: menu, multiple-choice

I have a batch file with multiple choices.  One of the choices will run all choices in order from 1-21.  What I'm trying to do is not run them in order but choose say 2,5,7,15,18,19,21 & run these chooses in that order.  How can this be accomplished??

Answer (score 0):

```
choice /c 123456789X
call :%errorlevel%
exit /b

:1
(choice 1)
exit /b

:2
(choice 2)
exit /b

etc.

:10
call 4
call 1
call 10
etc.
exit /b
```

`choice /c 123456789X` will return 10 if you press `X`.